# Verb to describe "to enable or to disable"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, hypernyms, programming

I'm looking for a word that describes "to enable or to disable". [This related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92781/what-term-describes-the-state-of-being-either-enabled-or-disabled) found the hypernyms *mode* and *state*, but I am looking for a verb. I.e. a word for "(potentially) change mode/state".

I guess *to switch* is a good match, but unfortunately in JavaScript (my target language), `switch` is a reserved keyword.

What alternatives are there?

Comment: Found myself wondering this exact thing.  Thanks for asking this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

May I suggest "to set availability"? I think it fits well for function names: SetButtonAvailability(), SetOptionAvailability(), etc. It's long, but descriptive...

Comment: along the lines of *set*, in my work i settled on set*SomeVariable*State. it avoids saying either enable or disable and it's shorter than availability.

Answer (score 21):

The verb form of *[toggle](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/toggle?view=uk)* can be used to indicate changing state

> [no object, with adverbial] Computing switch from one effect, feature, or state to another by using a toggle:
>   *the play/pause button toggles between those functions*
>   [with object]:
>   *there are a number of attributes which can be toggled on or off*

Comment: I thought of that. The problem of toggle is that it implicitly implies a change to a *different* state. I want to convey the possibility of staying in the *same* state.

Comment: @Randomblue How can the word describe, as you put it, "change mode or . . . change state" but also encompass "staying in the same state"?

Comment: Notice the "potentially" in brackets. I think the verb `to set` conveys that. "Set to the enabled state" and "set to the disabled state" do not make implicit statements about the previous state, but `to toggle` does.

Comment: “The problem of ‘toggle’ is that it implicitly implies a change to a _different_ state.”  So does “switch”.  How can you say, “I guess the verb `to switch` is a good match,…” if you want to encompass “staying in the same state”?

Comment: **togglable** even works some places: http://www.wordsense.eu/togglable/

Comment: @WayfaringStranger And *switchable*.

Answer (score 5):

The verb *to set* just jumped to mind.

Answer (score 2):

As I'm new, I'm not allowed to comment or vote up, but I like RegDwigнt's suggestion of set and availability wrapped around the item/control name.  For example, I have a Secure Team picker control that I am enabling/disabling in script, and I was wondering what to call it.  I'm going to adopt that convention and name the method SetSecureTeamPickerAvailability().  It's a bit long-winded, but very descriptive and self-documenting.

Answer (score 1):

"Toggle" is an excellent word for turning on or off.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure I grasp what you’re looking for, but it might be ***ensure***, as in “ensure that the ‘Help’ function is enabled.”  Or possibly ***affirm***, which seems to meld the concepts of “confirm” with the possibility of taking action to change the state.